# MS ACCESS Group/Sort Consecutively

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a problem while Using MS ACCESS. I have a table with about 1.2 Mio entries.

```
*Column1   Column2      Column3*    
**Name       Code         Datum**

aaa           111          01.01.01

aaa           111          02.01.01

aaa           222          03.01.01

aaa           222          04.01.01

aaa           222          05.01.01

aaa           111          06.01.01

aaa           111          07.01.01

aaa           111          08.01.01

bbb           333          01.01.01

bbb           333          02.01.01

bbb           111          03.01.01

bbb           111          04.01.01

bbb           333          05.01.01

bbb           333          06.01.01

ccc           222          01.01.01

ccc           222          02.01.01

ccc           222          03.01.01

ccc           222          04.01.01
```

This table should be summarized to:

```
**NAme      Code         ValidFrom     ValidTo

aaa           111          01.01.01        02.01.01

aaa           222          03.01.01        05.01.01       

aaa           111          06.01.01        08.01.01

bbb           333          01.01.01        02.01.01

bbb           111          03.01.01        04.01.01    

bbb           333          05.01.01        06.01.01

ccc           222          01.01.01        04.01.01
```

The Problem is that I have a VBA code which works with multiple recordsets, one is looping through the 1.2 mio entries and compares whether the Name and COde is the same and updates therefore keeps updating the Valid To date, as soon as one of them change the Name, Code and Valid From Date is taken from the first entry. After that the secon recordset is set on the level of the first recordset.
This method however takes hours....

Is there a more elegant way? Maybe with SQL? using group by and then min max for the dates. This idea came to my mind, but unfortunately I have repeating Codes within the same name. :-(

PS: Idially I need it the following form:

```
Name   Code            Valid From                     Valid to

aaa    111,222,111     01.01.01,03.01.01,06.01.01     02.01.01,05.01.01,08.01.01

bbb    333,111,111     01.01.01,03.01.01,05.01.01     02.01.01,04.01.01,06.01.01

ccc    222             01.01.01                       04.01.01
```

I am really grateful for your help and appreciate it.

regards

Comment: I can't see any way you can do this with ms-access SQL. A stored procedure in SQL Server could probably handle it efficiently. If you want to look at making your code more efficient, we can have a look at your looping and recordset queries. I don't see a way around using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an autonumber field to the table preserving the sort you displayed above?

If so here's my attempt at it:

```
SELECT Table1Start.id, Table1Start.Name, Table1Start.Code, Table1Start.Datum AS ValidFrom, 
    Min(Table1END.Datum) AS ValidThru
FROM 
    (SELECT Table1.* 
        FROM Table1
        WHERE ((((SELECT id FROM Table1 T WHERE T.id = Table1.id -1 AND
           (T.Name <> Table1.Name Or T.Code <> Table1.Code))) Is Not Null)) OR 
           (((Table1.id)=1))) AS Table1Start INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Table1.*
        FROM Table1
        WHERE ((((SELECT id FROM Table1 T WHERE T.id = Table1.id +1 AND 
           (T.Name <> Table1.Name Or T.Code <> Table1.Code))) Is Not Null)) OR 
           (((Table1.id)=DMax("id","Table1")))) AS Table1END 
        ON (Table1Start.Code = Table1END.Code) AND (Table1Start.Name = Table1END.Name)
WHERE (((Table1END.Datum)>[Table1Start].[Datum]))
GROUP BY Table1Start.id, Table1Start.Name, Table1Start.Code, Table1Start.Datum
ORDER BY Table1Start.id
```

That should get you as far as the first table summary at least.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses arrays via the GetRows function to process everything in memory.

It should scream thru your million rows assuming your data layout is like your example.

```
Public Sub ProcessDatumList()

    ' Change these values to match your query name and fields
    ' ***************************************************
    Const QRY_DATA_TABLE    As String = "data"

    Const FIELD_1           As String = "lookupname"
    Const FIELD_2           As String = "lookupcode"
    Const FIELD_3           As String = "lookupdatum"

    Const NAME_COL          As Integer = 0
    Const CODE_COL          As Integer = 1
    Const DATUM_COL         As Integer = 2
    ' ***************************************************


    Const BATCH_ROWS_TO_RETURN  As Long = 50000

    Const RS_SQL            As String = "SELECT [" & FIELD_1 & "],[" & FIELD_2 & "],[" & FIELD_3 & "] FROM [" & QRY_DATA_TABLE & "]"

    Dim rs                  As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL              As String

    Dim datum               As Variant
    Dim lngRowsReturned     As Long

    Dim lngRecNum           As Integer

    Dim strName             As String
    Dim lngCode             As Long
    Dim strDatum            As String

    Dim strFirstDatum       As String

    Dim strLastName         As String
    Dim lngLastCode         As Long
    Dim strLastDatum        As String

    Dim strCodeList         As String
    Dim strDatumFrom        As String
    Dim strDatumTo          As String

    Dim tim1                As Double
    Dim tim2                As Double

    strSQL = RS_SQL ' & ORDER_BY

    tim1 = Timer
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

    ' Get this started by loading first two rows
    If GetRowsOK(rs, 2, datum) Then
        ' Name = Field 1 : datum(0, intRecord)
        ' Code = Field 2: datum(1, intRecord)
        ' Datum = Field 3: datum(2, intRecord)

        ' Start from and to datum lists
        strFirstDatum = datum(DATUM_COL, 0) ' Record 1
        strLastDatum = datum(DATUM_COL, 1) '' Record 2

        ' Initialize code lists with first code
        strCodeList = datum(CODE_COL, 0)

        ' Store name of first two records
        strLastName = datum(NAME_COL, 1)

        strDatumFrom = strFirstDatum
    Else
        MsgBox "Problem Getting Data: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Error in Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do Until rs.EOF

        ' Loop by loading big batches of records into memory and processing arrays

        If GetRowsOK(rs, BATCH_ROWS_TO_RETURN, datum) Then
            lngRowsReturned = UBound(datum, 2) + 1 'records retrieved
            If lngRowsReturned > 0 Then

                For lngRecNum = 0 To UBound(datum, 2)

                    strName = datum(NAME_COL, lngRecNum)
                    lngCode = datum(CODE_COL, lngRecNum)
                    strDatum = datum(DATUM_COL, lngRecNum)

                    If strName = strLastName Then ' Update Code List

                        If lngCode <> lngLastCode Then ' New Code
                            ' Add new code to lists for code/datum from
                            strCodeList = strCodeList & "," & lngCode
                            strDatumFrom = strDatumFrom & "," & strDatum

                            ' Store last datum to match last name/code combo
                            If strDatumTo = "" Then
                                strDatumTo = strLastDatum
                            Else
                                strDatumTo = strDatumTo & "," & strLastDatum
                            End If
                        End If

                    Else
                        ' New Name and code
                        ' Store last datum to match last name/code combo
                        If strDatumTo = "" Then
                            strDatumTo = strLastDatum
                        Else
                            strDatumTo = strDatumTo & "," & strLastDatum
                        End If

                        ' write out full list for last name
                        Debug.Print strLastName, strCodeList, strDatumFrom, strDatumTo

                        ' Initialize new name, code and datum list
                        strCodeList = lngCode
                        strDatumFrom = strDatum
                        strDatumTo = ""

                    End If

                    ' Save values to compare to next record
                    strLastName = strName
                    lngLastCode = lngCode
                    strLastDatum = strDatum

                Next lngRecNum

' Write out last entry
                ' Store last datum to match last name/code combo
                If strDatumTo = "" Then
                    strDatumTo = strLastDatum
                Else
                    strDatumTo = strDatumTo & "," & strLastDatum
                End If

                Debug.Print strLastName, strCodeList, strDatumFrom, strDatumTo

            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Problem Getting Data: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Error in Data"
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    tim2 = Timer
    Debug.Print tim2 - tim1 & " seconds to complete"

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```